# Prove that $N(t,A):=\left|\left\{s\in(0,t]:\Delta X(s)\in A\right\}\right|$ has independent increments

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, levy-processes

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $(X(t))_{t\ge0}$ be an $E$-valued càdlàg Lévy process on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and$^1$ $$N(t,A):=\left|\left\{s\in(0,t]:\Delta X(s)\in A\right\}\right|\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge0$$ for some $A\in\mathcal B(E)$ with $0\not\in\overline A$.

> I want to show that $(N(t,A))_{t\ge0}$ has independent increments. A proof of this claim can be found in Theorem 2.3.5-(2) in the [book of Applebaum](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/levy-processes-and-stochastic-calculus/4AC698D37D3D8E57D099B73ADF4ACB11), but I don't get his argumentation:

[image: Theorem 2.3.5]

Regarding (2.3): Since $0\not\in\overline A$, $$r:=\operatorname{dist}(0,A)>0$$ and hence $$\left|\left\{t\in[a,b]:\Delta x(t)\in A\right\}\right|\le\left|\left\{t\in[a,b]:\left\|\Delta x(t)\right\|_E\ge r\right\}\right|\tag1$$ is finite for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and every càdlàg $x:[0,\infty)\to E$. But this only yields the existence of the $t_i$ (as claimed in the proof) which depend on $\omega$ or am I missing something?

Regarding (2.4): I actually don't get this. If $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ has a left-limit $t\ge0$, then it clearly holds that for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ with $$\left\|x(r)-x(t)+\Delta x(t)\right\|_E=\left\|x(r)-x(t-)\right\|_E<\varepsilon\tag2$$ for all $t\in(t-\delta,t)$. But this doesn't yield the "only if" part of the claim in the proof, since we cannot choose $a=\Delta X(\omega,t)$ (for some fixed $\omega)$, since we only know (by assumption) that $\Delta X(\omega,t)\in A$, which doesn't necessarily imply that $-a\in A$.

And the "if" part isn't clear to me at all.

How can we show these things rigorously?

**EDIT**: Assume $(X(t))_{t\ge0}$ is a Lévy process with respect to a filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$. Let $\tau_0:=0$. Then $$\tau_n:=\inf\{t>\tau_{n-1}:\Delta X(t)\in A\}$$ is a stopping time with respect to the right-continuous filtration $(\mathcal F_t^+)_{t\ge0}$. Moreover, $$N(t,A)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}1_{[0,\:t]}(\tau_n)\tag3$$ for all $t\ge0$. Now $$N(t,A)-N(s,A)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}1_{(s,\:t]}(\tau_n)\tag4$$ for all $t\ge s\ge0$. Since $1_{(s,\:t]}(\tau_n)$ is $\mathcal F^+_t$-measurable, for all $t\ge s\ge0$, $N(t,A)-N(s,A)$ is $\mathcal F^+_t$-measurable as well. But does this help?

---

As usual, $x(t-):=\lim_{s\to t-}x(s)$ and $\Delta x(t):=x(t)-x(t-)$ for every $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ with a left-limit at $t\ge0$.

Answer (score 1):

For (2.3), yes it depends on $\omega$. Also I think it should be
"$N(t,A)-N(s,A)\geq n$ if and only if there exists..." which makes more sense to me, and later we show instead $\bigl(N(t,A)-N(s,A)\geq n\bigr)\in\sigma\bigl(X(v)-X(u):s\leq u<v\leq t\bigr)$. This is still enough for proving independence as $$\bigl(N(t,A)-N(s,A)=n\bigr)=\bigl(N(t,A)-N(s,A)\geq n\bigr)\cap\bigl(N(t,A)-N(s,A)\geq n+1\bigr)^{c}.$$

For (2.4), there's a typo in it, it should be "$|X(u)-X(w)-a|<\varepsilon$". [See the errata here.](http://www.applebaum.staff.shef.ac.uk/Levcorr21.pdf) The statement "for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $0<u-w<\delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $|X(u)-X(w)-a|<\varepsilon$" is the exact definition of $\lim_{t\uparrow\uparrow u}X(t)=X(u)-a$. Also note that $\Delta X(u)=a$ $\iff$ $X(u)-\lim_{t\uparrow\uparrow u}X(t)=a$, hence the if and only if statement holds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's clearer to me now, but I still got trouble to conclude and I think the argumentation is more complicated than necessary. (a) First of all, given $u\in(s,t]$, I think in the second part the intention is to show that $\Delta X(u)$ is measurable wrt $\sigma(X(u)-X(w):w\in(s,u])$, right? Instead of arguing with the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-thing (from which the latter claim is not immediate; at least to me), wouldn't it be way more easier to use the fact that "limits of measurable functions are measurable"?

Comment: From this we should be able to obtain the claim by noting that $\Delta X(u)=X(u)-\lim_{n\to\infty}X\left(u-\frac1n\right)$, which is clearly measurable wrt $\sigma(X(u)-X(w):w\in(s,u)$. (b) Now, for every $u\in(s,t]$, $\sigma(X(u)-X(w):w\in(s,u])$ is clearly contained in $\sigma(X(v)-X(\tilde u):s\le\tilde u<v\le t)$. But how can we use the result obtained in (a) together with the first part in the proof of the book to conclude?

Comment: I think the crucial point is that $N(t,A)-N(s,A)$ is $\mathbb N_0$-valued, from which we know that $\sigma(N(t,A)-N(s,A))=\sigma(\{N(t,A)-N(s,A)=n:n\in\mathbb N_0)$. But how do we proceed? Since, as you noted, $(2.3)$ depends on $\omega$, this is not clear to me.

Comment: @0xbadf00d The first part is correct, it suffices to show the measurability of $\Delta X(u)\in A$. The first part is to show the set $\{\omega: N(t,A)(\omega)-N(s,A)(\omega)\geq n\}$ $=$ $\bigl\{\omega:\Delta X\bigl(t_{i}(\omega),\omega\bigr)\in A \text{ for }s< t_{1}(\omega)<\cdots<t_{n}(\omega)\leq t\bigr\}$ $=$ $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\bigl\{\omega:\Delta X\bigl(t_{i}(\omega),\omega\bigr)\in A\bigr\}$. The if and only if in (2.3) is to make sure these sets are equal. The second part is to show each set in the intersection is $\sigma\bigl(X(u)-X(w)\bigr)$-measurable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Well, that's my problem. You wrote $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}\bigl\{\omega:\Delta X\bigl(t_{i}(\omega),\omega\bigr)\in A\bigr\}$, but we cannot use the characterization of $\Delta X(u)\in A$, since your $t_i(\omega)$ depends on $\omega$. So, we also need to know something about the measurability of $\omega\mapsto t_i(\omega)$. I guess this can be fixed, by defining $t_i$ explicitly as a suitable stopping time, but without this argumentation, I don't see how the claim follows.

Comment: (BTW, I also think that your $n$ depends on $\omega$ as well.)

Comment: Please take note of my edit in the question.

Comment: @0xbadf00d $n$ will not depend on $\omega$, I'm fixing an $n\, (\text{and }s,t)$ and trying to capture the $\omega$ such that $N(t,A)-N(s,A)\geq n$. Thank you for the edit, it's helpful! I look back through the proof, seems we haven't used the independent increment of Lévy process. Maybe you can take $\tau_{0}:=s$, and now $\tau$s are independent of $\mathcal{F}_{s}$, maybe we can get closer to the desired measurability condition.